# Android SDK AsyncTask doInBackground not running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

plz help me

I did added async library at my project and checked already, I don't know why code flow doesn't go in to asynctask
my Update code doesn't execute.
in this line my update calss doesnt run

> dataupdate.execute();
>
> CODE:

```
public class Update extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

private String User;
private final String mLink;

public Update(String user) {
    User = user;
    mLink = "http://www./Update.php";
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(User, "UTF8");
        URL mylink = new URL(mLink);
        URLConnection connect = mylink.openConnection();

        connect.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            int f = 0, w = 0, C = 0;
            String name = null;
            String status = null;
            Integer money = null;
            boolean isDebtor = false;
            boolean isCreditor = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                if (line.charAt(i) == '|') {


                    if (w == 1) {
                        String temp2 = line.substring(f, i);
                        if (!temp2.equals(User)) {
                            isDebtor = true;
                            name = temp2;

                        }
                    } else if (w == 2) {
                        String temp2 = line.substring(f, i);
                        if (!temp2.equals(User)) {
                            isCreditor = true;
                            name = temp2;

                        }
                    } else if (w == 3) {
                        String temp2 = line.substring(f, i);

                        money = Integer.parseInt(temp2);
                    } else if (w == 4) {
                        String temp2 = line.substring(f, i);

                        status = temp2;
                    }
                    f = i + 1;
                    w++;
                }
            }
            Pair<String, Pair<Integer, String>> temp = new Pair<>(name, new Pair<>(money, status));
            if (isDebtor) {
                MainActivity.Debtor.add(temp);
            }
            if (isCreditor) {
                MainActivity.Creditor.add(temp);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Main:

```
        showProgress(true);
        dataupdate = new Update(username);
        dataupdate.execute();
       // dataupdate.execute((Void) null);

        showProgress(false);
```

Comment: Try new dataupdate.execute();

Comment: where is onPostExecute i can not find it in code

Comment: add a log in your catch block. Maybe your code raises an exception.

Comment: try new Update().execute();

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't an Exception? The catch block is empty.

Comment: Remove `showProgress(false);` line then check

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
public class Update extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
   User user=params[0]; //get string user value here
    try {
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF8");
        URL mylink = new URL(mLink);
        URLConnection connect = mylink.openConnection();
    connect.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        int f = 0, w = 0, C = 0;
        String name = null;
        String status = null;
        Integer money = null;
        boolean isDebtor = false;
        boolean isCreditor = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if (line.charAt(i) == '|') {


                if (w == 1) {
                    String temp2 = line.substring(f, i);
                    if (!temp2.equals(User)) {
                        isDebtor = true;
                        name = temp2;

                    }
                } else if (w == 2) {
                    String temp2 = line.substring(f, i);
                    if (!temp2.equals(User)) {
                        isCreditor = true;
                        name = temp2;

                    }
                } else if (w == 3) {
                    String temp2 = line.substring(f, i);

                    money = Integer.parseInt(temp2);
                } else if (w == 4) {
                    String temp2 = line.substring(f, i);

                    status = temp2;
                }
                f = i + 1;
                w++;
            }
        }
        Pair<String, Pair<Integer, String>> temp = new Pair<>(name, new Pair<>(money, status));
        if (isDebtor) {
            MainActivity.Debtor.add(temp);
        }
        if (isCreditor) {
            MainActivity.Creditor.add(temp);
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printstacktrace();
}
return null;
 }
}
```

to run
//put username value in execute

```
new Update()execute(username);
```